# Не удается удалить файлы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Недавно начал изучать Python, и решил сделать скрипт, который удаляет сохранений на кириллице в игре S.T.A.L.K.E.R. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой: файла не находит.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Скрипт для удаление сохранений на кириллице в игре S.T.A.L.K.E.R.
# Все информации и инструкция в файле readme.txt.

import os

alphabet = ('а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й',
               'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 
               'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я')

# Путь к сохранениям.
save_path = r'D:\Python\stalker\savedgames'

# Открываем файлы.
for top, dirs, files in os.walk(save_path):
    print('Количество файлов -', str(len(files)) + '.')
    for nm in files:

        # Выводим построчно каждый файл.
        print(os.path.join(top, nm))

        # Проверяем файлы на кириллицу.
        for letter in alphabet:
           if letter in nm:

            # Если находит файл на кириллице, тогда удаляем.
            os.remove(nm)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python\stalker\stalker.py", line 26, in <module>
    os.remove(nm)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 'Взорвать Сидоровича 2.sav'
```

Директория:

[image: Файлы]

Скрипт останавливается, когда уже находит файла на кириллице. Но если проверить на кириллицу - всё в порядке. Думаю, проблема одна - он не удаляет, выдает ошибку.

Comment: В дополнение к ответу, рекомендую обратить внимание на модуль `pathlib` и его класс `Path`. Подробности хорошо отражены в стандартной справке.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь удалить файл, но не говорите пайтону в какой папке он лежит, а указываете просто имя. Просто добавьте путь:

```
os.remove(os.path.join(save_path, nm))
```

Ответ на комментарий:

> А скажите, пожалуйста. Теперь там двойные бэкслеши, и не находит файла
>   из-за это. Как избавиться от них?

Проблема не в двойных слешах и не в том, что файл не находит, а то вы пытаетесь удалить файл несколько раз, следовательно, если вы уже удалили файл, второй раз пайтон его не найдет. Добавьте `break` в ваш последний цикл:

```
import os

alphabet = ('а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й',
               'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 
               'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я')

# Путь к сохранениям.
save_path = r'E:\project\python project\test\test'

# Открываем файлы.
for top, dirs, files in os.walk(save_path):
    print('Количество файлов -', str(len(files)) + '.')
    for nm in files:

        # Выводим построчно каждый файл.
        print(os.path.join(top, nm))

        # Проверяем файлы на кириллицу.
        for letter in alphabet:
           if letter in nm:

            # Если находит файл на кириллице, тогда удаляем.
            print("delete")
            os.remove(os.path.join(save_path, nm))
            break
```

Comment: Правильно использовать os.path.join(), а не собирать путь самому.

Comment: @Эникейщик а чём это лучше?

Comment: Тем, что если в конце save_path окажется символ "\", ваш способ не сработает. Тем, что на другой ОС ваш способ не сработает. Тем, что не нужно заморачиваться разделителями уровней, все сделают за вас.

Comment: @Эникейщик Убедительно) Поправил ответ

Comment: А скажите, пожалуйста. Теперь там двойные бэкслеши, и не находит файла из-за это. Как избавиться от них?

Comment: @Ryan ответил в ответе

Comment: Спасибо Вам, благодарю.